# Sorted linked list function (C)

Tags: c, sorting, data-structures, linked-list

I'm a beginner who has been self-teaching for the past weeks data structures. I'm trying to create a function that inserts an integer into a linked lists in a sorted fashion.

Here's my function:

```
void sortedInsert(int n)
{
    node *temp = malloc(sizeof(node));
    temp->data= n;

    //if list is empty or n is less than minimum number in the list, insert at the beggining.
    if(head == NULL || n < head->data )
    {
        temp->next = head;
        head = temp;
    }
    else
    {
        node *cur, *prev, *temp;
        for (cur = head, prev = NULL
             cur != NULL && cur->data < n;  //if n is less than cur->value it breaks out of loop
             prev = cur, cur = cur->next);

         //now cur is pointing at last node or the node it broke out off

         if( n < cur->data)
         {
             temp->next = cur;
             prev->next = temp;
         }
         else
         {
             //if its larger than the maximun number in the list
             //insert at end 
             temp->next = NULL;
             cur->next = temp;
         }

         free(cur);
         free(prev);
    }
}
```

Output:

```
How many numbers?
4
Enter the number
10
List is:  10
Enter the number
4
List is:  4 10
Enter the number
5

Process returned -1073741819 (0xC0000005)   execution time : 7.161 s
Press any key to continue.
```

It crashes out whenever I insert a number greater than those on the list.
I'll appreciate any help or guidance I could get.

Comment: If you have calls to `free` in your insert functions, you are doing it wrong. Can you justify these calls?

Comment: 1) `if( n < cur->data)` need check of `cur != NULL` 2) `free(cur);
        free(prev);` are wrong. 3) `for (cur = head, prev = NULL` --> `for (cur = head, prev = NULL;`

Comment: Are both of the free functions incorrect?

Comment: Do not free nodes in the link list.

Comment: You free *nodes* (not pointers) you no longer need. Can a list after an insertion contain one less node than before?

Comment: Yeah, very dumb mistake. Freeing nodes would only break the list.

Comment: Actually you are right... those are pointers. It makes sense now...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The erroneous behavior is in the for loop inside the else statement. That loop terminates in two conditions. The first is, if a node with data that is greater than or equal to n is found. The second is when cur is NULL. If you traverse all the list before finding a node with a value greater than or equal to n, the loop will terminate when cur becomes NULL.

Therefore you need to check if cur is NULL or not, and you should not use it as if it will definitely be a value that is not NULL.

To achieve the behavior you desire, I believe you should get rid of the if-else statement following the for loop and instead just use the two lines below.

```
temp->next = cur;
prev->next = temp;
```

In addition to that, before the for loop, you declaring temp variable once more causes temp you declared in the beginning of the function to be inaccessible for that scope. That second declaration should be removed as well.

Finally, although you did not specify the desired behavior of your function, based on the semantic implications of the name of your function, I believe you do not need to make calls to free(), and you should remove them.

So, after making the changes I mentioned, here's how your code should look.

```
void sortedInsert(int n)
{
    node *temp = malloc(sizeof(node));
    temp->data= n;

    //if list is empty or n is less than minimum number in the list, insert at the beggining.
    if(head == NULL || n < head->data )
    {
        temp->next = head;
        head = temp;
    }
    else
    {
        node *cur, *prev;
        for (cur = head, prev = NULL
             cur != NULL && cur->data < n;  //if n is less than cur->value it breaks out of loop
             prev = cur, cur = cur->next);

         //now cur is pointing at last node or the node it broke out off
         temp->next = cur;
         prev->next = temp;
    }
}
```

Comment: Makes sense. In the `for loop`, would  breaking out if  `cur->next = NULL`, fix this?

Comment: The program is crashing when I used the code above @ilim.

Comment: I forgot to remove the redefinition of temp variable inside else. I fixed it now, you may try again.